# what is the sql query to get the details in between 365 to 500 days , from today?

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

get the details in between 365 to 500 days, from today

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from YOURTABLE WHERE DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -365 DAY)  < CURDATE() < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 500 DAY)
```

Comment: Got this error "'CURDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name."